An easy to remove mechanism to RC control steering on a 2012 Ford Fusion
I have a 2012 Ford Fusion that I purchased on Facebook market place as a project.  I intend to only use it on the parking lot near my house which is almost always empty.
I would like to add the ability to RC control the car steering.  Looking on YouTube there are many solutions but almost all of them don't leave room for the driver.
I would prefer it if I can sit in the car normally, drive it to the parking lot normally, and then enable RC steering.
Things that I have attempted so far:

Cut a gear in half and welded it to the steering column, just behind the steering wheel.  Then mounted a DC motor on the dash and used a chain to drive the column.
Principally this is sound, because the original Stanford self driving car Stanley did this.  But my execution was sloppy and instead of turning the column, it pulls it towards the motor.
I tried mounting it above the column, but again it's just not a good solution.

Reverse engineering the lane keep assist EPS ECU.  This works a bit, however there's a min speed limit since this is meant only on the highway, and also a torque limit for the same reason.


The next option is somehow mount a linear actuator, but that's going to be very limited in max steering rate ( I believe).
What options do you guys think I can try next?

The way it is done for testing production cars is to mount a toothed pulley, roughly the same diameter as the steering wheel, to the steering wheel, and drive it with a little motor. The system has to be stabilised by a link between the motor, steering wheel, and the structure of the car, as the forces are non trivial.
https://www.abdynamics.com/track-testing/driving-robots/sr60-orbit/
